# How can I add more text after the chapter name in a book

Tags: xetex, chapters, titlesec, books, arabic

I am trying to typeset the Quran in LaTeX using XeLaTeX and arabxetex. For chapter pages, I want the English text on the left, and the Arabic text on the right. The result should be something like this:

[image]

Here is what I have so far:

```tex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}

\usepackage[paperwidth = 6 in,paperheight = 9 in,margin = 0.75 in,bindingoffset = 0.125 in]{geometry}

% Use the Quran version of the Amiri font
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri Quran}

% Use "Surah" instead of "Chapter"
\renewcommand\chaptername{Surah}

% English on the left, Arabic on the right
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[fullvoc]{arabxetex}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter \hfill \textarab{سورة \surahnum}}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{40pt}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\newcommand\surahnum{1}
\newcommand\surahname{الفاتحة}

\chapter{Al-Faatiha}

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

What's missing is the Arabic name of the surah (chapter) on the right side of the English name of the surah. The Arabic name of the surah can be accessed with the command `\textarab{\surahname}` Of course I can do this:

```tex
\chapter{Al-Faatiha \hfill \textarab{\surahname}}
```

But that also changes the appearance of the chapter name everywhere, and I only want the Arabic version to show here. **Is it possible to use titlesec to add text *after* the chapter name?** I can add text before it like this:

```tex
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter \hfill \textarab{سورة \surahnum}}{0pt}{\Huge\hfill\textarab{\surahname}}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{40pt}
```

[image]

I need the `\hfill\textarab{\surahname}` to come *after* the chapter name, not *before*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can load `titlesec` with the option `explicit`. Then you can insert the title as `#1` in the correct place:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}

\usepackage[paperwidth = 6 in,paperheight = 9 in,margin = 0.75 in,bindingoffset = 0.125 in]{geometry}

% Use the Quran version of the Amiri font
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri Quran}

% Use "Surah" instead of "Chapter"
\renewcommand\chaptername{Surah}

% English on the left, Arabic on the right
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[fullvoc]{arabxetex}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
   {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
   {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter \hfill \textarab{سورة \surahnum}}
   {0pt}
   {\Huge  #1\hfill\textarab{\surahname}}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{40pt}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\newcommand\surahnum{1}
\newcommand\surahname{الفاتحة}

\chapter{Al-Faatiha}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the working solution!

Answer (score 2):

You could also create a 'fake' chapter command for the Arabic title and set it in `twocolumn`:

```
\documentclass[oneside,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[fullvoc]{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri Quran}
\usepackage[transen]{quran}
\renewcommand\chaptername{Surah}
% fake chapter command
\newcommand{\chapterarab}[1]{%
\vspace*{-120pt}
{\huge\textarab{سورة \thechapter}\par\vspace*{20pt}
\Huge\textarab{#1}\par\vspace*{30pt}}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Al-Faatiha}
\quransurahen[1]
\newpage % column break
\begin{arab}[utf]
\chapterarab{الفاتحة}
\quransurah[1]
\end{arab}
\end{document}
```

[image]